# Convergence in SOT and norm boundedness in $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ equivalent to norm convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras

Let $S_\infty$ - permutation group of the natural numbers fixing all but a finite number of element. And let $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ - reduced group $C^*$-algebra that acts on $\ell_2(S_\infty)$ in obvious way.

Let $A_n \in C_r^*(S_\infty)$ is a sequence of operators that bounded by norm (i.e. exist $C>0$ such that $||A_n||<C$ for each $n$) and $\operatorname{lim-SOT} A_n = A_\infty$ (SOT - strong operator topology) is that true, that $\operatorname{lim} A_n = A_\infty$ (in norm topology)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely no. There is no infinite-dimensional context where you could make that kind of deduction.

If that property were true, the unit ball of $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ would be SOT-closed, which would make $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ a von Neumann algebra; and this is impossible, since $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ is separable, while any infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra is not norm-separable.

**Comment 1.** *The sot-closure of $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ is very very very well-known: it is the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor.*

**Comment 2.** The group $S_\infty$ plays absolutely no role here. For any countable infinite group, the answer will be no.

**Comment 3.** The assertion fails even in a von Neumann algebra. For instance, consider the von Neumann algebra $B(H)$ with $H$ separable. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}\subset H$ and let $E_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $e_n$ (that is, for each $n$ $E_nx=\langle x,e_n\rangle\,e_n$). Let $A_n=\sum_{k\geq n}E_k$. Then $A_n\to0$ sot, but $\|A_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks! And it is not true even for SOT-closure?

Comment: Not at all. Please see Comment 3 in the answer.

Comment: Maybe in every von Neumann algebra it false but in hyperfinite type II_1 is true?

Comment: Not at all. In any  II$_1$-factor, let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of pairwise orthogonal projections, with $\tau(P_n)=2^{-n}$. Let $A_n=\sum_{k\geq n}P_k$. Then $A_n\to0$ sot, while $\|A_n\|=1$ for all $n$. You can pretty much do this in any infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Thanks, for your explanation!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Could you please look my new question, if you have time?